# How to debug UPDATE execution in mysqli driver

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, mysqli

I've looked over a lot of posts, but I still can't figure why this simple UPDATE is failing to affect the database:

---

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$quantityArray = array();

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $quantityArray[$key] = $value;
}

foreach ($quantityArray as $key => $value) {
    $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $value);
}

foreach ($quantityArray as $key => $value) {
    $query = "UPDATE inventory SET quantity = $value WHERE uniqueID = $key";

echo "<br /><br / >" . $query . "<br /><br / >";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

echo "<br /><br / >" . $result . "<br /><br / >";

}
```

---

When this script is called, $_POST is an array of unique IDs as keys and quantities as values (both of which are integer values). I've tested and confirmed that, yes, only the appropriate keys and their values are being passed, so why this isn't working is a mystery to me.

UPDATE: $result returns nothing at all

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This would be a perfect opportunity to use a prepared statement.

Comment: have you tried printing out what the actual query says?

Comment: If you don't check the return value of **all** the mysqli calls, and **log the error messages when a failure happens**, you're doomed to never figuring out why your code fails.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Right now I'm having the code post the query to the browser as well and it looks fine to me: UPDATE inventory SET quantity=10 WHERE uniqueID=1

Comment: Have you printed out your query and tried to run it directly on the database?

Comment: Mat, the system I'm using reports errors to the browser automatically, but point taken. Right now I'm not getting any errors, it just fails to actually update the table

Comment: it seems right to me. Are you sure `uniqueID` matches an id in the database? try to run it directly to phpmyadmin

Comment: Mat, you're right, I'll look into prepared statements for future projects

Comment: Okay, good call trying it directly in phpmyadmin, I don't know why I didn't think of that. It worked just fine from phpmyadmin, so something else must be the issue here

Comment: @user2363734 - in that case, start echoing out the error messages you're getting back from the database; and indeed checking the return values from your queries.

Comment: Okay taking everyone's recommendations into thought, I've revised it to look as is shown above

Comment: So big discussion. Sir, what about to see if mysqli got some error? mysqli_error( $con );

Comment: Okay, well there you go. Good learning experience: mysqli_error: UPDATE command denied to user 'user'@'localhost' for table 'inventory'... not really sure how to address that from cpanel or phpmyadmin though

Comment: Zelioboba, thank you for your help. It turns out that although I'd created a new user in CPanel to use this database with, the user was not given appropriate access rights to use UPDATE. I switched the command to use the default user in mysqli_connect() and that solved the problem.

Comment: @user2363734 Fine! Then close the question please. I've provided resume answer to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments we've got a simple solution: `mysqli_error( $con );` helped to figure out that default user right was not enough to perform UPDATE operations for specified table. Adding new user with appropriate rights solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
$query = "UPDATE inventory SET quantity=" . $value . " WHERE uniqueID=" . $key;
```

with

```
$query = "UPDATE databasename . inventory SET quantity=" . $value . " WHERE uniqueID=" . $key;
```

Comment: Isn't the fully qualified table name 'databasename.tablename', rather than username?

Comment: the database is specified in the mysqli_connect(). Also, I tried this code, but still no good... UPDATE: tried using the database name as well, but the field still isn't getting updated

Comment: Yeah sorry, it must be UPDATE databasename . inventory etc.., try it and tell me if works :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `UPDATE` statement doing update correctly, But you are looking to wrong database to check it!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$query = "UPDATE inventory SET quantity = $value WHERE uniqueID = $key";
```

Comment: it's just the same with the original post.

Comment: echo $query;
exit;
     
Do you get any errors if you run that result directly in phpMyAdmin?